# How to extract the numbers in a file in C++?

Tags: c++11

I have some similar files like this:
15 12
0 0 168
0 2 92
(more numbers)...

I want to extract the first two (in this case: 15 and 12) into integers, how can I accomplish that?
By the way, the first two numbers sometime will be unit digits sometimes will be hundreds digits.

Comment: You can make a program that uses std::cin to read input you type. Then when it works pipe the file. `C:\x < numbers.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of the language, this will typically consist of the following steps:

1. Open the file
2. Read (formatted) the first two integers
3. Close the file

In C++, we can use `ifstream`

1. To open:

```
std::ifstream fil;
fil.open("in.txt");
```

2. To read:

```
int x, y;
fil >> x >> y;
```

3. To close:

```
fil.close();
```

Make sure to include the `fstream` header:

```
#include <fstream>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't expect this was that easy. But what if I want to extract every number after the first two and store them in an array? And also I got many numbers in the file, I don't want to define lots of ints in the code, is there an alternative?

Comment: If you know how many ints you're reading, you can just loop through an array and read one by one: `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { fil >> arr[i]; }`